# Spock functional tests are failing on Chrome and IE because of Proxy settings

Tags: grails, functional-testing, spock, geb

This is bit of a strange issue. 
I have number of Spock tests (functional tests) and I have been running these perfectly fine on all the browsers (namely, IE-10, FF and Chrome). But just recently I have hit a stumbling block where I'm not able to run the tests consistently well, this is since I started using the Proxy settings (that the brilliant IT dept. has introduced).

Strangely enough, my tests still run fine on Firefox but they fail on IE and Chrome. All I know is that they all have the same Proxy settings.

I use the following code to create an instance of the driver in Gebconfig.

```
driver = {
if (!System.getProperty("webdriver.ie.driver"))
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\code\\IEDriverServer.exe")       
}
    new InternetExplorerDriver()
}
```

I use similar code for other browsers too.

Is there a peculiarity in the implementation of these browsers. Do the instances use the current user profile. Can someone please help resolve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the proxy settings directly as DesiredCapabilities when building your driver instance, see the section on using a proxy [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)